# How to make usernames clickable like the Twitter and Facebook app?

Tags: java, android, regex, linkify

The twitter and facebook apps allow you to click on a username which in turn takes you to a new activity. How can this be achieved?

I know there is Linkify, but it seems like it can only send you to a browser/phonecall/ etc. How can I make text that are like "@mynamehere" clickable so that it starts a new activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to detect your link (using regular expressions for example) and then you have to attach a [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) to your text.
You have an example [here](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to match tags that start with @ and replace them with a link. Something like this:

http://granades.com/2009/04/06/using-regular-expressions-to-match-twitter-users-and-hashtags/